# Why is inheritance depth significant in Datanucleus JDO on GAE?

Tags: java, oop, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

### If I have one level of inheritance, everything is persisted as expected in App Engine:

Worker.java

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Inheritance;
import javax.jdo.annotations.InheritanceStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Worker {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String department;
}
```

Employee.java

```
// ... imports ...

@PersistenceCapable
public class Employee extends Worker {
    @Persistent
    private int salary;
```

}

Intern.java

```
import java.util.Date;
// ... imports ...

@PersistenceCapable
public class Intern extends Worker {
    @Persistent
    private Date internshipEndDate;
}
```

### However, if I add one additional layer of inheritance, the fields in the highest level subclass are not persisted:

Human.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
public abstract class Human {

    @Persistent
    private String name;
}
```

Worker.java

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Worker extends Human {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String department;
}
```

### Why is it ok to extend an abstract class but not ok to have that abstract class extend a higher level class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And your Primary key is now not in the root class of the (persistable) inheritance tree, hence invalid by the JDO and JPA specs.

Comment: Following your advice I moved the Primary key field from Worker into Human. Now, when I instantiate an Employee I get the error: `Exception: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Found inheritance strategy 'superclass-table' on com.foo.Employee. This strategy is not supported in this context.`

Comment: So specify the inheritance strategy on that class ! as per the JDO spec

Answer (score 0):

You should also move the following declaration to the Human class:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
```